# Need assistance regarding creating auto layout constraints programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

This is the first time I am trying to create `auto layouts  constraints` programmatically and here is my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc]init];
    view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [self.view addSubview:view1];
    [view1 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

    NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(view1);

    NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-[view1]-|" options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing metrics:nil views:views];

    NSArray *verticalConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[view1]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];

    [view1 addConstraints:constraints];

    [view1 addConstraints:verticalConstraints];
}
```

This is what I amy trying to do in code.

[image]

And this huge error I am getting

> 2015-12-16 12:13:59.254 test5b[1138:430691] The view hierarchy is not
>   prepared for the constraint:    When
>   added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that
>   view (or the view itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to
>   be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled. Break on
>   -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:] to debug. 2015-12-16 12:13:59.259 test5b[1138:430691] View hierarchy unprepared for
>   constraint.   Constraint: 
>     Container hierarchy:  >     View not found in container hierarchy: >     That view's superview: ; layer = > 2015-12-16 12:13:59.260 test5b[1138:430691] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException',
>   reason: 'Unable to install constraint on view.  Does the constraint
>   reference something from outside the subtree of the view?  That's
>   illegal. constraint:
>   view:>'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x1829f4f5c 0x1975e7f80 0x1829f4ea4 0x183890ef4 0x18804c620 0x18804c428 0x18804c2d0 0x18804c194
>   0x188056504 0x183890aa0 0x18805330c 0x188056420 0x1000d65f0
>   0x187f63a0c 0x187fd2fcc 0x187fd2f68 0x1881f494c 0x188200de4
>   0x1829ac48c 0x1829abdc4 0x1829a9d28 0x1828d8dc0 0x18da2c088
>   0x187fb2f60 0x1000d6ab8 0x197e128b8) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add constraints to `self.view`. Replace the following:

```
[view1 addConstraints:constraints];
[view1 addConstraints:verticalConstraints];
```

with

```
[self.view addConstraints:constraints];
[self.view addConstraints:verticalConstraints];
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, but why self.view, I want these to be on view1 like we do in storyboard ctrl+drag from view1 to super view...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177262/centering-subviews-x-in-autolayout-throws-not-prepared-for-the-constraint

Provide a good reason for why we add constraint to self.  View1 is not in view hierarchy.

Comment: why view1 is not in hierarchy I did [self.view addsubview:view1] and If I apply same in storyboard and select the view1 then in size inspector all constraints appear for view1.

Comment: You are setting constraints so a view knows how to layout it's subviews. A view doesn't have itself in its subview hierarchy...

Comment: @Irfan Thanks a lot :).

Comment: As of iOS 8, you should no longer use `addConstraints:`. Use `+[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:]` or `-[NSLayoutConstraint setActive:]`.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Thank you so much